# Event listeners for both radio buttons and text input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group of radio buttons and a text input field:

```
<div>
      <input type="radio" value="0.1" id="radioOne"   name="discount"  />
      <label for="radioOne" class="radio">10%</label>
</div>
<div>
      <input type="radio" value="0.2" id="radioTwo"   name="discount" />
      <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">20%</label>
</div>
<div>
      <input type="radio" value="0.3" id="radioThree"  name="discount" checked />
      <label for="radioThree" class="radio">30%</label>
</div>

<input type="number" name="price" id="priceInput" placeholder="Price">

<p id="resultToast"> </p>
```

And I wanna the result of final price calculated by *Price * Discount* and updating the `<p id="resultToast"> </p>`.
So I did

```
const radios = document.querySelector('input[name="discount"]:checked');
const toast = document.querySelector('#resultToast');
const priceIn = document.querySelector("#priceInput");

if (radios) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="discount"]').forEach((elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
       radios.value = event.target.value;
       console.log(radios.value);
        if(priceIn){
          toast.textContent = 'final price:  ' + radios.value * priceIn.value;
        }
    });
  });
}

if(priceIn){
  priceIn.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
}

function updateValue(e) {
  toast.textContent = 'final price:  ' + e.target.value * radios.value;
}
```

From the console, the `radios.value` not updated correctly after clicking the radio buttons. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
const radios = document.querySelector('input[name="discount"]:checked');
```

To:

```
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="discount"]:checked');
```

See working snippet:

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="discount"]:checked');
const toast = document.querySelector('#resultToast');
const priceIn = document.querySelector("#priceInput");

if (radios) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="discount"]').forEach((elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
       radios.value = event.target.value;
       console.log(radios.value);
        if(priceIn){
          toast.textContent = 'final price:  ' + radios.value * priceIn.value;
        }
    });
  });
}

if(priceIn){
  priceIn.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
}

function updateValue(e) {
  toast.textContent = 'final price:  ' + e.target.value * radios.value;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <input type="radio" value="0.1" id="radioOne"   name="discount"  />
      <label for="radioOne" class="radio">10%</label>
</div>
<div>
      <input type="radio" value="0.2" id="radioTwo"   name="discount" />
      <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">20%</label>
</div>
<div>
      <input type="radio" value="0.3" id="radioThree"  name="discount" checked />
      <label for="radioThree" class="radio">30%</label>
</div>

<input type="number" name="price" id="priceInput" placeholder="Price">

<p id="resultToast"> </p>
```

Reason for this is because you stored the initial

```
document.querySelector('input[name="discount"]:checked');
```

value as `radios`. Now that we look for all, it changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to a constant you defined at the beginning of your script. This will always give you the same radio button value (the one being checked at the beginning). Do something like

```
let discount=document.querySelector("input[name=discount]:checked").value
```

within your event handler function to get the current value of the radio button group.

You could also declutter(=shorten) your code a bit and make it reusable for multiple input sections that way, see below:

```js
function qs(sel,el){return (el||document).querySelector(sel);}
function makeInteractive(frmsel){
  const frm=qs(frmsel),
        prc=qs("[name=price]",frm),
        res=qs(".result",frm);
  frm.onchange=calc;
  frm.oninput= calc;
  function calc(){
    res.textContent=
      (prc.value * qs("[type=radio]:checked",frm).value)
      .toFixed(2);    
  }
}

makeInteractive("#frm1");
makeInteractive("#frm2");
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
the first item ...
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" value="0.1" name="discount"/>10%</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" value="0.2" name="discount"/>20%</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" value="0.3" name="discount" checked/>30%</label>
</div>

<input type="number" name="price" id="priceInput" placeholder="Price">

<p id="resultToast" class="result"> </p>
</form>

<form id="frm2">
the second item ...
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" value="0.1" name="discount"/>10%</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" value="0.2" name="discount"/>20%</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" value="0.3" name="discount" checked/>30%</label>
</div>
<input type="number" name="price" id="priceInput" placeholder="Price">

<p id="resultToast" class="result"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Alternatively if he does ``const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="discount"]:checked');`` works too

Comment: Yeah I changed to `let` but the issue remains. If I refresh the page, one radio button does not get updated after clicking